# HomeKit doesn't work if I'm connected to my lan network over VPN

Tags: applet, homekit

I have some IoT in my house and are also added to my Home app from my Iphone.
I don't have a Hub for this, can be accessed only from my local WiFi and that's what I actually want.

I also have a VPN inside my router so I can access my local WiFi from anywhere.
The problem is that I can't access my devices from my Home app while connected to my VPN inside my router. I'd like to mention that I can access them with the specific app (e.g. I can turn off/on the lights inside Hue App, but not Home App when outside my WiFi but connected to it via VPN).

Is it there a port that needs to be forwarded or something that I need to do from my end to be able to manage everything with Home app and not be forced to go the each app specifically?

Regards,

Comment: I'm stuck in the exact situation. Did you find a solution to this?